# Are Japanese people aware of the Chinese meanings of Kanji?

Tags: kanji, chinese

I'm not sure if I've got the right wording in the question, but it comes from playing around with translate.google.com.

I was aware that Japanese and Chinese have similar (if not identical) characters (I'm a Westerner, so again, I apologise if this is all just wrong).

So, for a laugh, I entered my name in English and translated it to Chinese.

I then took that Chinese translation and told Google it was Japanese and then translated it back to English.

Some names were just non-sensical. I also think some of the translations have improved over time.

For example, my name Richard, is translated to Chinese as 理查德. Treating that as Japanese, it becomes Ri-sense back in English.

A couple of years ago, it was management (or middle management - I can't quite remember).

I was demonstrating this to my work colleague Joe. Joe didn't do anything as there seems to be no translation of 乔 from Japanese to English.

But when I tried his full name of Joseph, ... well ... embarrassment all round.

In Chinese, Joseph translates to 约瑟夫. If this was Japanese, translating it to English is a quite an offensive word.

Is this a fluke?

Are there any rules about what characters are used?

I suppose one rule is don't get a Chinese tattoo of your name and visit Japan if your name is Joseph!

Comment: I don't know much Chinese but I think the characters in 理查德 are used phonetically, not for the meaning

Comment: Putting Google Translate aside, 乔 and 约 never exist in Japanese. Those are Simplified characters (of 喬 and 約) only in currency in mainland China (and around Singapore). 查 is the same character as Japanese 査 but was assigned separate code due to technical reasons, so it's also a non-Japanese character for computers.

Comment: If enough users suggest something as a translation, Google Translate will eventually assume that to be correct. This has led to other funny things, like [this](https://translate.google.com/#de/tr/%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4%C3%A4).

Comment: Just as a remark, I think it's not correct to say that "in Chinese, Joseph translates to 约瑟夫". In fact, for proper name "translation" means simply finding characters with the closest sound to the original pronunciation. Probably that example is coming from a specific Joseph (some famous character.. Bible Joseph?) but it would not be wrong if for your own name or your friend's you choose three completely different characters with similar phonetic.

Comment: Some Chinese words that the Chinese are using today are actually created by the Japanese, like 人民、電話、服務、民主、革命、哲學、化學、經濟、科學、商業、幹部、健康、社會主義、資本主義、法律、封建、共和、美學、文學、美術、抽象 ...

Comment: Kanji are, after all, a system of ideograms originating in China. Because they are ideograms they do have a meaning, and their meanings are mostly the same whether they're used in China, Japan, Korea or Vietnam. HOWEVER, they don't need to represent their meanings, and sometimes can't represent its inherent meaning (e.g., in phonetic translations of foreign words, or in Japanese as ateji). 约瑟夫 and 理查德 are used as phonetic transcriptions; the characters carry no semantic meaning at all when used this way; no one could possibly be aware of something nonexistent.

Comment: @DavidWashington To be exact, some are not from scratch but recycled. As I remember, at least 人民, 革命, 封建 and 共和 in your list are already attested (with more or less similar meanings) in ancient documents.

Comment: Heh, that's genius. I imagine that was spiked by user contributions. Someone _really_ doesn't like his/her friend Joseph (or was playing a prank). And got the language wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To native speakers of Japanese, 理查德 and 约瑟夫 mean nothing. To me, they are just some random kanji, most of which are unfamiliar. (Japanese people only use 理 and 夫.) I don't even know if it's a proper noun, a full sentence, or complete gibberish. All I can say is that they are kanji, and may or may not mean something for Chinese speakers.

I also tried Google Translate to translate "约瑟夫 as Japanese" to English, but I have absolutely no idea why they showed this word. You should know Google Translate is not a grammar/spell checker. It almost never complains. Even if you entered complete gibberish, it often shows something that may look meaningful.

As for the *Chinese* rule of choosing characters for westerner names, perhaps this question at Chinese Language SE helps:

- [mandarin - How do we choose the correct characters for a westerner name? - Chinese Language Stack Exchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/242)

Regarding how such names would look to Japanese people, it's very unlikely that such Chinese-Western names happen to mean something in Japanese. Usually they only strike us as unfamiliar characters which are "presumably Chinese".

Comment: Thank you for the comments. It was just the silliness of Google translating what I naively took to be valid symbols for 2 languages. An idle curiosity.